# Do we need to use from a list or in a list in this sentence - "Click on an asset from/in the Recently delivered assets list"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Scenario - There are many assets (computers, chairs, keyboards) displayed in a list  (e.g. Recently delivered assets) in a software. I need to click on an asset (e.g. computer) that is listed in Recently delivered assets.

How do I need write that -

"Click on an asset from the Recently purchased assets list"
"Click on an asset in the Recently purchased assets list"

Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: I am looking for which once is grammatically correct but not sure if a preposition is not grammatically correct then how it can be appropriate. Can you please write a few lines to help me out here.. Thank you @KillingTime

Answer (score 0):

The important part is the action, i.e. "Click on". While you are choosing an item (a recently delivered asset) *from* the list, the action you are performing is clicking on one of the items that is (displayed) *in* the list.

So the correct sentence would be:

> Click on an asset in the Recently purchased assets list.

That said, most users would interpret it the same way if you used the 'from' variant.

Comment: Thanks @killingTime May I know if there is any scenario when "from" could sound appropriate?

Comment: If editing for a software manual, I would remove the redundant preposition and just write *click an asset . . .*